# Laravel - Passar Variável Para View - Página Registro

Tags: php, laravel

Estou utilizando **Laravel 5.8** e adicionei um campo a mais no cadastro de usuários. Quero inserir um form select nesse campo mas, estou com dificuldade.

O que eu imaginei que daria pra fazer, era isso no arquivo  **RegisterController.php** (`\app\Http\Controllers\Auth`):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');

        $setores = \App\Setores::all();
        return view('auth.register', compact('setores'));
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'setor_id' => ['required'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'setor_id' => $data['setor_id'],
        ]);
    }


}
```

E isso:

```
  <select id="setor_id" name="setor_id">
  @if(count($setores)>0)
  @foreach($setores as $set)
   <option value="{{ $set->id }}" selected="selected"> {{ $set->nome }} 
   </option>
  @endforeach
  @endif
```

No arquivo **register.blade.php** (`\resources\views\auth`)

Mas, estou recebendo o seguinte erro como retorno:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>
> Undefined variable: setores (View: C:\xampp\htdocs..._...\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Alguém sabe como eu poderia passar essa variável para minha **View** `register.blade.php`?

Comment: Tem certeza que `view('auth.register', compact('setores'))` deveria estar no `__construct()` e não no método relativo ao `register.blade`?

Comment: Então. Eu não encontrei onde é chamada essa view. Vou postar todo o conteúdo do meu RegisterController.

Comment: Procure  o método `register()` na classe `RegistersUsers` e sobrescreva esse método na sua classe `RegisterController` adicionando a variável `$setores` à sua view

Comment: Achei essa classe RegisterUsers.php e coloquei direto nela essa variável na chamada da View. Muito obrigada, Erlon!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `RegisterController` implementa a trait `RedirectsUsers`, nessa trait ela implementa o metodo `showRegistrationForm()` que é o método que é chamado quando você acessa a rota `/register`, então basta você sobrescrever o método dentro do `RegisterController`, ficaria algo assim:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $setores = Setor::all();

    return view('auth.register', compact('setores'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Então cara, a forma que eu conheço pra fazer isso é definir no controller da view as variáveis que você quer passar na view. Eu geralmente faço da seguinte forma:

```
//Crio uma função INDEX para carregar a tela:

public function index() {

//aqui faço toda a lógica e tratativa, e após isso dou um return:

return view('sua_view.index', [
         'variavel1' => $variavel_definida_na_lógica_acima
        , 'variavel2' => $variavel_definida_na_lógica_acima
        , 'variavel3' => $variavel_definida_na_lógica_acima
        , 'variavel4' => $variavel_definida_na_lógica_acima
        , 'variavel5' => $variavel_definida_na_lógica_acima
    ]);
}
```

Depois que você ajustar a view e o retorno das variaveis, o erro mencionado (Undefined variable:) desaparece, e você pode chamar as variáveis dentro da view, que no caso seria

```
{{variavel1}} / {{variavel2}} / {{variavel3}} / {{variavel4}} / {{variavel5}}
```

Dai pra fazer o foreach funcionar, não esqueça de atribuir obviamente nas variáveis o tipo array, e depois só seguir o que você já estava fazendo.
Comigo funciona perfeitamente assim, e sinceramente acho que fica até mais organizado.
Espero ajudar.

Comment: Assim não dá certo pra mim. Eu coloquei o conteúdo a View Register acima.

Comment: Os Controllers gerados pelo Auth são diferentes. Não são dessa forma.